# Динамическое добавление данных в data-функцию Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Коллеги, есть ли у кого идеи или реализовать ли кто-то мысль в сторону создание одного модального окна для редактирования разных сущностей.

Чтобы реализовать надуманное мне нужно как-то динамически изменять объект data() в самом компоненте

https://github.com/RasankRam/black_list_frontend/blob/main/src/components/modal_create.vue

К сожалению, задумка не получилась (в watch'e заполняется как раз объект $data --> this.$data[key] = '', так как я не смог найти способа динамического добавления данных в объект, который возвращается функцией data()

Comment: Добавь [repro] (в запускаемой форме, т.е. сниппетом)... возможно, я знаю способ (но сначала его проверить надо).

Comment: заюзайте computed или state.store